# R: How to tidy data contained in a single column into separate columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

My data frame is not tidy:

```
name   information
A      300 USD
A      70 kg
A      2 cm 
B      400 USD
B      90 kg
B      5 cm
```

How can I tidy up the 'information' column into separate variables/columns: USD, kg, and cm using dplyr, tidyr and possibly other packages?

Here is the desired output:

```
name   USD    kg    cm
A      300    70    2
B      400    90    5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `separate/spread` from `tidyr`.  The `separate` splits the 'information' column into two columns and then with `spread` we reshape it to 'wide' format after changing the 'unit' to `factor` class (in case the order of columns are important).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, information, into = c("value", "unit")) %>% 
               mutate(unit= factor(unit, levels =unique(unit))) %>%
                spread(unit, value)
#  name USD kg cm
#1    A 300 70  2
#2    B 400 90  5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), information = c("300 USD", 
"70 kg", "2 cm", "400 USD", "90 kg", "5 cm")), .Names = c("name", 
"information"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example using tidyr's spread:

Let's say that we have a dataframe, df, which contains columns for 'id', 'date', 'element', and 'measurement':

**df**

```
id  date        element measurement

01  2018-02-06  tmax    55

01  2018-02-06  tmin    51
```

This data frame is not tidy because there are 2 rows for the same id '01', and we should only have 1 row. We can use 'spread' to spread the values 'tmax' and 'tmin' across columns.

**df %>% spread(key=element, value=measurement)**

```
id  date        tmax tmin

01  2018-02-06  55    51
```